# Decoding ogg and other compressed audio file formats with Android SDK (OpenSL)

Tags: android, android-ndk, ogg, opensl

The documentation of OpenSL, that states
"Supported formats include WAV PCM, WAV alaw, WAV ulaw, MP3, Ogg Vorbis, AAC LC, HE-AACv1 (aacPlus), HE-AACv2 (enhanced aacPlus), AMR, and FLAC [provided these are supported by the overall platform, and AAC formats must be located within an MP4 or ADTS container]. MIDI is not supported. WMA is not part of the open source release, and compatibility with Android OpenSL ES has not been verified."

Elsewhere, in forums, I have read that OpenSL on Android doesn't support the decoding of any compressed format. Since the implementation of the decoder using the OpenSL API seems  a task that requires at least some hours to be implemented, I would love to understand if I can be sure that once I have put in place all the required boiler-plate code for the decoding I won't find myself with the surprise of not being able to read any compressed format, especially OGG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding ogg vorbis with OpenSL works. It even does sampling rate conversion, which is handy. Although I have found that the end of the stream is not signaled with the event `SL_PLAYEVENT_HEADATEND`. In case of `mp3` or `wav` 'decoding' this event is dispatched. This is not necessary a dealbreaker, b/c you can figure it out that the decoding was finished in other ways.

I eventually added the ogg vorbis sources to my project because I wanted to have more control over the decoding: This way I can tell in advance how long is the decoded clip, for example, but I had to do the sample rate conversion myself.

Comment: Sure, do you have some money to share? B/c it looks like you have no technical difficulties, but want to outsource this task without spending time on it... (And I don't want to be rude, I'm just asking...)

Comment: I hoped it was part of a public project. I need to say that for such time consuming, annoying tasks that aren't really original programming ideas but can eventually be considered all boilerplate code, I am always up to share. for example creating a Gist.

Comment: If you want to use OpnenSL, look at the native-audio example project in android-ndk. (Wheteher the played audio is a wav file or ogg, doesn't matter.) And you have to change the player's sink to a buffer queue, similar to the recorder example in the same project. If you want to include ogg/vorbis sources to your project look at how libgdx does. (Or just use libgdx instead)